# How can I run a matrix test from a pipeline job and get the results back?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a matrix job that runs a single test on several iPads. I also have a pipeline job that I'd like to run that matrix job. Then I'd like the pipeline job to take the passing tests from the matrix job and kick off another job and pass the name of the passing jobs in as a parameter. Is this possible? I am able to kick off the job with:

`healthchecktests = build 'name-of-healthcheck-job'`

And I can tell if it passed by using

`def testResult = healthchecktests.result
echo testResult`

But I can't figure out how to get information about the individual matrix tests.